# jquery if no change made to the input field after 10 seconds, show this Div

Tags: jquery

I have a button that changes to a form on click. How do I change it back after 10 seconds if nothing is inputted (if the form is still empty)?

Update:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function (){
            $.ajax({
                    success: function(html){
                    if(html){
                    $('#btn').replaceWith('<input class="offer_pay_form" type="text"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></span>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please add some sample code (prefferrably runnable, at http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.com), and tell what you've researched/tried before asking the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: updated. I searched around but didn't know how to say "if no change"

Comment: look at `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this

```
setTimeout(function(){
if($("input").val()=="")
{
    alert("you havent input anything yet");
}},10000);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mcLAa/)

Instead of replacing. try like this way

```
<input type="button" id="btn" />
 <div id="container"></div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                success: function (html) {
                    if (html) {
                       $(this).hide();
                        $('body').append('<div id="newData"><input class="offer_pay_form" type="text"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></span></div>');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            if ($(".offer_pay_form").val() == "") {
                                $("#newData").hide();
                                $("#btn").show();

                            } 
                        }, 10000);

                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: this worked! only thing is, if I have a button that is replaced with a text field, and nothing is inserted in the text field, once the button replaces the text field, it is no longer working. how can I make it work each time the button is on the page?

Comment: did you add  <div id="container"></div> ??

Comment: quick thing, if the user inputs something then deletes it, the form doesn't go away.. is there a way to make it keep checking if it's empty?

Comment: yes, you can use the .change() method of input. In that you can use the setTimeout again

Comment: how do I tell it: if the form is empty (after entering and removing something), then hide..? change is just to check if it changed anything, i don't want it to hide the form if they type something

Comment: can you add it as another question with more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
  if($('#txt').val() == ""){
      $('.div').fadeIn();
  }    
},10000);
</script>

<input type="text" id="txt" />
<div class="div" style="display:none;">Testing div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u6UEp/)